# set UISearchBar Focused programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, focus, uitabbarcontroller, uisearchbar

i have 2 tabs on a UITabBarController, a navigation inside each tab, and on the first one a tableViewController with searchBar.

On the second tab, i have another searchBar, but, i want to set the onClick of this one, go to the first tab and focus the search bar.

i currently can redirect the tap on the searchbar to the other tab, but i dont know how to set the focus.

```
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    UINavigationController *tmp = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [tmp popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    UIViewController *vc = tmp.topViewController;//THIS ONE

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    return NO;
}
```

The UIViewController that i've got on the code, has the UISearchBar object that i need, i mean, the superClass.h is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MasterTableViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objects;//stuff
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *results;//stuff
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;//THIS IS MY UISearchBar !

@end
```

my problem is that i can't get that UISearchBar, how should i do it ? 
and how can i say it to be focused from the `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` Method on the other tab ?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your searchbar delegate method and check below:-

```
      - (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
```

Comment: ?? i haven't ask for the method, the ´searchBarShouldBeginEditing´ is just to catch when the search bar have been touched, as u seen, the code redirects the tab bar controller to another tab, and, on that new tab is where i need help, so, wrong answer, or details missing...

Comment: You need to call becomeFirstresponder for searchbar to set the focus

Comment: if u read the question, it says "my problem is that i can't get that UISearchBar, how should i do it ?" i don't know how to get my UISearchBar from the object that i get on the code,  (UIViewController *vc), if i cast get an error if i try to get it as a property i get error...

The first responder maybe works, but i cant use it yet...

go ahead

Comment: You can check the condition wrting view.subviews in for loop and then putting check if view iskindofclass:[UISearchBar class]…